# Understanding how laser pulsing is characterised

Tags: photonics

I'm trying to understand how laser pulsing is characterised. My understanding is that we can characterise pulsed lasers as pulsing a certain amount per second (pulses per second). Furthermore, my understanding is that there are two parameters involved here: (1) the pulses themselves, at some amount of seconds/milliseconds/microseconds/nanoseconds/etc., and (2) the frequency of these pulses, defined in terms of Hz/kHz/MHz/etc. However, I'm not sure that I concretely understand what these mean, and the difference between them. Am I correct here in my understanding of how laser pulsing is characterised? What are these two laser pulsing parameters? What is the difference between these two laser pulsing parameters?
And, as an example to help me understand this better, if we had, say, a laser with 3-nanosecond pulses at a repeating frequency of 5 kHz (these seem like reasonable values, based on my research), what does this actually mean? And how would we calculate the pulses-per-second of such a pulsed laser?

Comment: I'm a bit confused: the amount of pulses per time **is** the frequency of the pulses. So your (1) and (2) would be identical...

Comment: @mmmm Yes, I find it a bit confusing as well, which is why I'm asking all of this. But I think my description is correct; see here https://www.quora.com/How-many-times-does-a-laser-pulse-per-second "A pulsed laser is defined by its pulse duration (in units of femtoseconds, picoseconds, or nanoseconds) and its repetition rate (usually in units of MHz or kHz)."

Comment: But your characterization (you can characterize anything, the question is whether it's useful; for example, the cleanliness of the laser light' wavelength might be important to you, or it might not) is missing the aspects you care about. Is it the speed at which the laser becomes fully on?

Comment: Well that sentence hits a very important thing: I can shout for a second once every minute or once every hour. I can do the same, but shouting for 10 s.

Comment: @mmmm I'm interested in the parameters I mentioned: (1) the pulses themselves, at some amount of seconds/milliseconds/microseconds/nanoseconds/etc., and (2) the frequency of these pulses, defined in terms of Hz/kHz/MHz/etc. I should have been more clear.

Comment: @mmmm hmm, that's a good example. So the seconds/milliseconds/microseconds/nanoseconds/etc. are actually how long the pulse lasts for? So, using my example, if the pulse is 3 ns, then the pulsed laser would effectively operate as a CW / emit for a full 3 ns, and then stop emitting? And at 5 kHz frequency, it would do this 5000 times per second?